# Why is 'serialize' method generating an empty array from my form in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a form partial with various input fields using the Simple Form Gem in my Rails app. One of the questions is a checkbox input field and the user can select multiple values with questions relating to diet and lifestyle (do you drink coffee, eat white bread?... etc). On the database, the corresponding column (named 'tick') is a string input field.

## What I wanted to do

I wanted the user to select as many checkboxes as necessary and for those options to be displayed in the 'Show' view once the user submits the form. The raw output should have been an array with the numbers corresponding to the selected checkboxes in the form.

## What I did to achieve this

I used the serialize method https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class
to try to save the inputs as an array which would be retrieved from the database in the show view. see the implementation below in the model and controller.

## What actually happens

Once the user submits the form they are redirected to the 'show' view where the corresponding HTML output is simply "[]" with no actual answer given. See HTML output below:

```
<p>
  <strong>Pon un tic en las Casillas si son aplicables en tu caso:</strong>
  []
</p>
```

The Form partial: _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@formulario) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if 
  f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
.
.
.
.
<%= f.input :tick,
    label:'Pon un tic en las Casillas si son aplicables en tu caso',
    collection: [
    ['padecido desorden alimentaria?', '1'],
    ['comes mucho lacteo o trigo?', '2'],
    ['te gusta comer/preparer comida?', '3'],
    ['compras comida ecológica?', '4'],
    ['añades sal a la comida?', '5'],
    ['tomas café o té descafeinado?', '6'],
    ['usas margarinas?', '7'],
    ['cocinas con aceites vegetales?', '8'],
    ['bebes agua filtrada?', '9'],
    ['has cambiado tu dieta ultimamente?', '10'],
    ['tomas té o café?', '11'],
    ['comes pan blanco?', '12'],
    ['comes mucho comida frita?', '13'],
    ['compras mucha comida para llevar?', '14'],
    ['comes mucha fruta y verdua fresca?  ', '15'],
    ['añades muchas salsas a la comida?', '16'],
    ['comes fuera a menudo?', '17'],
    ['cocinas para mas personas?', '18'],
    ['tienes apetito grande?', '19'],
    ['tu dieta es repetitiva?', '20'],
    ['comes pasta y arroz?', '21'],
    ['comes comida preparada?', '22'],
    ['usas el microondas?', '23'],
    ['eliges comida bajo en grasa?', '24'],
    ],
    as: :check_boxes %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

The Show view: show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
.
.
.
<p>
  <strong>Tick:</strong>
  <%= @formulario.tick %>
</p>
.
.
.
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_formulario_path(@formulario) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', formularios_path %>
```

The Formularios model, formulario.rb

```
class Formulario < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :tick, Array
end
```

I have also tried changing the params hash in the Formulario controller from

```
..., :tick, ....
```

to

```
..., tick: [], ...
```

and also

```
..., (tick: []), ...
```

which gave a syntax error "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>"

Formularios controller.rb

```
    class FormulariosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_formulario, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :new]
  # before_action :user_signed_in?, only: [:show, :new]
  before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:show, :index]

  # GET /formularios
  # GET /formularios.json
  def index
    @formularios = Formulario.all
  end

  # GET /formularios/1
  # GET /formularios/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /formularios/new
  def new
    @formulario = Formulario.new
  end

  # GET /formularios/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /formularios
  # POST /formularios.json
  def create
    @formulario = Formulario.new(formulario_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @formulario.save
        format.html { redirect_to @formulario, notice: 'Formulario was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @formulario }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @formulario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /formularios/1
  # PATCH/PUT /formularios/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @formulario.update(formulario_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @formulario, notice: 'Formulario was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @formulario }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @formulario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /formularios/1
  # DELETE /formularios/1.json
  def destroy
    @formulario.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to formularios_url, notice: 'Formulario was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def authenticate_admin
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

    # def authenticate
    #   authenticate_user! && current_user.admin?
    # end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_formulario
      @formulario = Formulario.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def formulario_params
      params.require(:formulario).permit(:nombre, :fecha, :FdN, :direccion, :sexo, :email, :telefono, :movil, :profesion, :altura, :peso, :motivos, :especialistas, :dieta, :intolerancia, :detalles_1, :limites, :otro_1, :problema1, :p1, :p2, :p3, :problema2, :p4, :p5, :p6, :problema3, :p7, :p8, :p9, :problema4, :p10, :p11, :p12, :otro_2, :medicacion1, :m1, :m2, :m3, :m4, :m5, :m6, :medicacion2, :m7, :m8, :m9, :m10, :m11, :m12, :medicacion3, :m13, :m14, :m15, :m16, :m17, :m18, :otro_3, :suplemento1, :s1, :s2, :s3, :s4, :suplemento2, :s5, :s6, :s7, :s8, :suplemento3, :s9, :s10, :s11, :s12, :otro_4, :madre, :padre, :abuela_mat, :abuela_pat, :abuelo_mat, :abuelo_pat, :hermanos, :hermanas, :tios, :tias, :ninos, :sobrinos, :activa, :ejercicio1, :e1, :e2, :ejercicio2, :e3, :e4, :ejercicio3, :e5, :e6, :otro_5, :fumas1, :fumas2, :fumado, :alcol1, :alcol2, :alergia1, :alergia2, :habitos1, :habitos2, :habitos3, :habitos4, :galletas_tartas_bolleria, :leche, :huevos, :chocolates_dulces, :carne_roja, :carne_blanca, :pescado_blanco, :pezcado_azul, :carne_procesada, :pan, :te, :cafe, :refresco_lata, :agua, :verdura, :ensalada, :tick, :pecho, :dieta_sana, :motivacion, :desayuno1, :desayuno2, :desayuno3, :almuerzo, :almuerzo2, :almuerzo3, :cena1, :cena2, :cena3, :snacks1, :snacks2, :snacks3, :bebidas1, :bebidas2, :bebidas3)
    end
end
```

How can I get the serialize method to save the array? or is there an alternative method I can use to achieve the same thing? i.e. record which of the checkboxes are selected in the form and display them in the show view.

Comment: Could you please add the raw params received by your controller into the question? Also, if you could add the `create` / `update` action to the controller that'd be handy too.

Comment: Your also missing the show action in your controller. I also think you made a typo in *#formulario_params*, I guess `:tick [],` should be `tick: [],` furthermore you want to pass the scalar attributes before the alternate values (arrays, hashes), meaning that `tick: []` should come after `:bebidas3`. You can also have it in-between, but than it should look like this: `{tick: []}`.

Comment: @SRack what do you mean by raw params? how can I find them? i have added the full controller file

Comment: @JohanWentholt {tick: []} worked. now it produces an array in the show view. do you know if there ia a way to use the labels in the form to be displayed in the show view too? because at the moment just an array e.g. [1,2,3,5,24] is returned which is fairly menaingless without the labels.

Comment: try to print here what you see in the rails server logs when the form submits so we can see how the params are being received in create controller action or just force in create action a puts plus inspect for formulario_params and prints the result here or by another side you can use the gem byebug and try to figure out what happens in create action too def create byebug @formulario = Formulario.new(formulario_params)

Comment: @Owen I'm not too familiar with simple form, but can't you just pass an array of names as the collection? eg. `['padecido desorden alimentaria?', 'comes mucho lacteo o trigo?', ...]`. Keep in mind that only one value can be hold by a checkbox, meaning you'll lose the id. If you want both the id and value you might want to move tick to it's own model or create a helper, than fetch the names using the ids.